Amazon Connect integration with SAP S4CRM/ API Integration
How to integrate Amazon Connect with SAP S4CRM or can amazon connect with integration using API instead of directly opening the CCP.
Basically a custom CCP has to be call Amazon Connect API's
Currently in SAP these inputs are required
You maintained remote function call (RFC) destinations in transaction SM59:
Use G Connection type (HTTP Connection to External Server).
Under Technical Settings, use:
Target Host: 
PathPrefix: 
Service No: 

Depends on what exactly you want to do. If you need phone functionality, there is no way around native CCP and calling Amazon Connect from the user's browser. However, while native CCP must be used, you can hide it with CSS and replace the UI with something else. The native CCP has a Javascript API known as "connect streams", which allows you to build a custom CCP with a different UI.
